# Class test in ABAP class builder

Tags: abap

I'm trying to test class from within of ABAP class builder. I pressed F8 (Test) but `Create instance` menu item is not active on test screen:

[image]

My class has both static and instance constructors. Where is my mistake? How to force this menu item to be active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this parameter set to `public`?
[image]

Moreover, if it is, then it is probably because your class implements an interface. Just click the magnifying glass icon next to the interface name and you will both be able to execute static and instance methods.

Comment: oops, it was embarassing... In my case, class instance has been already created. This menu item is active only when class has static methods. In case of static free class - instance automatically created after you've pressed F8 in class builder. Thank you very much for your help!